# State-like mechanism for storing object, but reading changes to it immediately?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose I need to store an object in React state, so I call:

`const [myObject, setMyObject] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});`

Somewhere in my component, I have a callback that handles an event and needs to do a bit of complex validation.  There are multiple places where it might need to update that object in state, and there are multiple other places where it might need to read that object from state, including the aforementioned updates.  That is, I have code like:

```js
const handler = useCallback(() => {
     // perform some complex validation
     if (foo()) {
          setMyObject(prev => ({...prev, x: 1}));
     }
     // perform some more complex validation
     if (bar() && myObject.x === 1) {
         setMyObject(prev => ({...prev, y: 2}));
     }

}, [myObject]);
```

The idea is that I want the second `if` to detect that the value of `myObject.x` is now 1.  I know there are 2 reasons this won't work exactly as written:

1. React state setter methods don't update state immediately, but queue an update to run before the next "render tick".
2. Even if the setter did run immediately, the previous value of `myObject` was captured in `handler`'s closure and would not update to refer to the new object instance.

My question is, is there a common way to get around this problem that won't break React?  Some possibilities I've thought of and rejected:

1. Directly assign to properties on the `myObject` instance. Unfortunately I've heard that directly mutating a state object this way is a bad idea, even if I were to immediately call `setMyObject` afterward with the new values to ensure components that take `myObject` as a prop will re-render.
2. Store `myObject` in a ref called `myObjectRef`, and always update `myObjectRef.current` whenever I make changes. Since `myObjectRef` itself (the wrapper) is always the same, I don't have to worry about it being stale in a function's closure, and `myObjectRef.current` will always give me the latest instance of the object, so I could change the second `if` to

```
if (bar() && myObjectRef.current.x === 1) { ... }
```

The problem with this approach is that React doesn't listen to changes to a ref, so passing myObjectRef.current to a child component would not cause that component to re-render on change (and isn't advised anyway).

Is there a common React idiom for having an updateable value that can be passed down to components and causes them to re-render as it changes, but is also available on-demand for code to read its latest contents at any time?  I know I could make a copy of myObject at the top of the method and update that copy as I go, passing it into the setMyObject calls, but that is basically duplicate bookkeeping that I'd like to avoid (especially if I split the complex logic into helper methods--then I'd need to pass the copy in as a parameter even though myObject itself is in scope, which feels needlessly cumbersome).

I've thought about this, and one idea I have is to create a hook with the following characteristics:

- Returns a pair of methods: `getMyObject()` and `setMyObject()`
- Rather than storing `myObject` as state, the hook stores `myObject` in a ref called `myObjectRef` (not exposed to consumers of the hook)
- `getMyObject()` always returns `myObjectRef.current`
- `setMyObject()` takes in a partial `myObject` and creates a new instance merged with the current instance, storing it in `myObjectRef`
- `getMyObject` (the function) is actually stored in state, and anytime `setMyObject` causes a change, `getMyObject` is replaced with a new copy of the same function with the same implementation
- Any sub-component that would have taken `myObject` as a prop takes `getMyObject` instead (the function itself, not the value obtained from calling it). As such, combined with how `geMyObject` is replaced with an identical copy on update, that sub-component will re-render as `myObject` changes.
- As a convention for users of the hook, in addition to never directly mutating the object obtained from `getMyObject()`, they should always read the value of myObject by calling `getMyObject()`, and avoid storing the result in a variable for very long (basically, always call `getMyObject()` again if there was any opportunity for things to change in between).

Is there any fundamental rule of React that I'd be breaking by doing this?  Or a more commonly used and intuitive way of getting what I'd want?

Comment: Easiest would just be to clone the state object at the top of the function, do whatever you need to to this object, then at the end of the function set the state to this new object. This means you can do direct object mutations, and only call set state once. There are downsides but nothing major, like having to clone the object (negligible in most cases) and also means you might call set state unnecessarily if none of the if conditions are met (though you can solve this with a single bool to track whether _any_ changes have been made)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're very much overthinking it.

If your code performs an operation, whether or not you can yet observe the result of that operation, you still know that the code performed it.  You can track that in a variable.  For example:

```
let fooResult = foo();
if (fooResult) {
  setMyObject(prev => ({...prev, x: 1}));
}
if (bar() && fooResult) {
  setMyObject(prev => ({...prev, y: 2}));
}
```

Or as a separate value:

```
let updatedToOne = false;
if (foo()) {
  setMyObject(prev => ({...prev, x: 1}));
  updatedToOne = true;
}
if (bar() && updatedToOne) {
  setMyObject(prev => ({...prev, y: 2}));
}
```

Any way you structure it, you don't need to track if *state was updated* (it hasn't been yet), you can just track if *you queued an update*.  Basically, "did this `if` block execute or not?"  You don't need React for that.

Comment: I understand I can track these changes in a local variable...I'm asking if there's a good way to avoid having to do that (avoiding "duplicate bookkeeping" as I mentioned in the question) because as the code gets more complex this becomes more cumbersome and error prone to do, and if I'm already changing the value in state (or a substitute state-like mechanism) then I shouldn't have to change it in a second place as well.